# swift 3 error: Type 'AVLayerVideoGravity' has no member 'resizeAspectFill'

Tags: ios, swift3, avfoundation, avplayerlayer

I am working on an iOS app using Swift 3 where I have a video playing in the background. My code was working completely fine until randomly the error message:

> Type `AVLayerVideoGravity` aka (`NSString`) has no member `resizeAspectFill`

appears. I can't figure out at all why resizeAspectFill is no longer being recognized. Is there something I'm missing? I've tried cleaning my project but that does not fix anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated :) 
Below is the code:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
// MARK: Properties
var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
var paused: Bool = false

var enterButton: UIButton! = UIButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Welcome"

    let theURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"hannah", withExtension: "mp4")

    avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: theURL!)
    avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
    avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

    avPlayer.volume = 0
    avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .none

    avPlayerLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                           object: avPlayer.currentItem)
```

Comment: Maybe try taking out the period, so it's `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill`...

Comment: I tried that- for swift 3 its been renamed so that the period is necessary

Comment: Which Xcode version are you running on?

Answer (score 9):

From the [documentation of AVPlayerLayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlayer/1388915-videogravity) (unfortunately the link redirects to the Swift 4 version. To see the changes enable *Show API changes* at top right).

> The video gravity determines how the video content is scaled or
>   stretched within the player layer’s bounds. The player layer supports
>   the following video gravity values:
>
> - AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
> - **AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill**
> - AVLayerVideoGravityResize
>
> The default value is `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect`.

---

**The enum case you are referring to belongs to Swift 4**

Answer (score 3):

You need to say:

```
avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill .rawValue
```